# How to set environment variables to run ROS project using Qtcreator?

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, ros

Using Qtcreator to run the ROS projects I get the following error:

> FATAL] [1473647395.591961066]: ROS_MASTER_URI is not defined in the
>   environment. Either type the following or (preferrably) add this to
>   your ~/.bashrc file in order set up your local machine as a ROS
>   master:  export ROS_MASTER_URI=http ://localhost:11311  then, type
>   'roscore' in another shell to actually launch the master program.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your ROS environment as you usually do in your `.bashrc` and simply launch Qt Creator from terminal. That's it. ;) This will make your ROS variables visible to the IDE.

Comment: When I followed the above procedure .I am not able to run the project as it shows no target file. So I followed http://sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-qt-creator-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ this procedure. It solved the target problem but I  get the above error.

Comment: I have added the lines in to the .bashrc file as export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost/11311

Comment: Thank u I solved by starting it via terminal after setting up the file.

Comment: So it worked or it did not? I'm getting mixed messages from your 3 comments.

Comment: Now it works. above 3 comments from me were the procedure I followed .thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe that running QtCreator from terminal every time is not quiet a good idea. You'll probably forget it one time and that will be a freak show (It used to work !!).

So, I advise taking a look at the following page explaining How to [Setup Qt Creator for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator) once and for all.

```
> Note that instead of starting QtCreator from a terminal, you can use the following desktop file and use it in your launcher:

$ cat qtcreator.desktop  
[Desktop Entry] 
Exec=bash -i -c qtcreator %F
Icon=qtcreator 
Type=Application 
Terminal=false 
Name=Qt Creator
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment 
MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;application/x-designer;application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile;application/vnd.nokia.xml.qt.resource;
Categories=Qt;Development;IDE; 
InitialPreference=9

> In Ubuntu 13.04 and later, the third line must read:

Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
```